# Java service to convert xls files to HTML

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns

I have a service that converts an Excel spreadsheet file into HTML. It is working just fine, but it is quite a big method that doesn't follow any SOLID principles. Therefore I would like to improve it to follow at least the Single Responsibility Principle. But I really don't know how to apply it and find the level of abstraction in my case.

```
@Service
public class xlsToHtmlImpl implements MultipartFileToHtmlService {

private final HtmlLayout htmlLayout;

@Autowired
public xlsToHtmlImpl(HtmlLayout htmlLayout) {
    this.htmlLayout = htmlLayout;
}


@Override
public InputStream multipartFileToHtml(MultipartFile multipartFile, boolean hasOnlyOneSheet, boolean hasBorders) throws IOException {

    String fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
    BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(multipartFile.getInputStream());

    Workbook workbook;
    assert fileName != null;
    //Selecting workbook depending on FileType
    if (fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(htmlLayout.FILE_TYPES[0])) {
        workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    } else {
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    }
    //Writing content of multipartFile to outputstream
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(htmlLayout.openStyle());

    //Selecting style to apply depending on user input
    if (hasBorders) {
        outputStream.write(htmlLayout.noBordersStyle());
    } else {
        outputStream.write(htmlLayout.withBordersStyle());
    }
    outputStream.write(htmlLayout.closeStyle());

    outputStream.write(htmlLayout.openNewHtml());
    outputStream.write(fileName.getBytes());


    //Different algorithm for the content of the body depending on user input
    Sheet sheet;
    if (hasOnlyOneSheet) {
        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.rowIterator();
        while (rows.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rows.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cellIterator();
            outputStream.write(htmlLayout.newLine());
            outputStream.write(htmlLayout.newRow());
            while (cells.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cells.next();
                outputStream.write(htmlLayout.newCell());
                outputStream.write(cell.toString().getBytes());
                outputStream.write(htmlLayout.closeCell());

            }
            outputStream.write(htmlLayout.closeRow());
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i< workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
            sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
            Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.rowIterator();
            outputStream.write(htmlLayout.newLine());
            outputStream.write(htmlLayout.newRow());
            outputStream.write(htmlLayout.closeCell());
            outputStream.write(htmlLayout.closeRow());
            outputStream.write(htmlLayout.newLine());
            while (rows.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rows.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cellIterator();
                outputStream.write(htmlLayout.newLine());
                outputStream.write(htmlLayout.newRow());
                while (cells.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cells.next();
                    outputStream.write(htmlLayout.newCell());
                    outputStream.write(cell.toString().getBytes());
                    outputStream.write(htmlLayout.closeCell());

                }
                outputStream.write(htmlLayout.closeRow());
            }
        }
    }

    outputStream.write(htmlLayout.newLine());
    outputStream.write(htmlLayout.closeHtml());
    outputStream.close();

    //Returning result as ByteArrayInputStream to controller
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
}
```

Where `htmlLayout` contains a HTML snippet like:

`public byte[] closeHtml() {return "</table></body></html>".getBytes();}`

I tried to follow the advice given in *[Single Responsibility Principle in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-single-responsibility-principle#:%7E:text=As%20the%20name%20suggests%2C%20this,only%20one%20reason%20to%20change.&text=These%20classes%20are%20harder%20to%20maintain.)*.

Following this article, I created different classes as follows:

```
public class HtmlStyleWrapper {

private byte[] style;


public byte[] withBordersStyle() {
    return ("table, td{" +
            "    border: 1px solid black;\n" +
            "    border-collapse: collapse;\n" +
            "    padding: 9px;\n" +
            "}").getBytes();
}

public byte[] noBordersStyle() {
    return ("td {" +
            "    padding: 9px;\n" +
            "}").getBytes();
}

public byte[] openStyle() {
    return "</title></head><body><style>".getBytes();
}

public byte[] closeStyle() {
    return "</style><table>".getBytes();
}

public void wrapStyle(ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream, boolean hasBorders) throws IOException {
    outputStream.write(openStyle());
    if (hasBorders) {
        outputStream.write(noBordersStyle());
    } else {
        outputStream.write(withBordersStyle());
    }
    outputStream.write(closeStyle());
}


public class HtmlBodyWrapper {

private byte[] body;

public byte[] openNewHtml() {
    return "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>".getBytes();
}

public byte[] newLine() {
    return "\n".getBytes();
}

public byte[] closeHtml() {
    return "</table></body></html>".getBytes();
}

public byte[] newRow() {
    return "<tr>".getBytes();
}

public byte[] closeRow() {
    return "</tr>".getBytes();
}

public byte[] newCell() {
    return "<td>".getBytes();
}

public byte[] closeCell() {
    return "</td>".getBytes();
}

public void wrapBody(ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream, String fileName, boolean hasOnlyOneSheet, Workbook workbook) throws IOException {
//Write to outputstream
}
```

The aim would be to get something like

```
wrapHTMLBody(wrapStyle(htmlLayout.getHTML_STYLE()), table)
```

But I feel like I'm not taking the right approach and that I didn't correctly understand SRP.

Answer (score 1):

To do a better design, I think you need to know what features you will need.
The needs should drive your API and design.
The danger to create new classes without a knowldege af future needs, is that you can do bad choices, bad abstractions the leads to a complicated interface / API.

For now, it is most important to make your code cleaner I think : split your big parsing method in smaller ones for example, or avoid the duplication between one sheet or many sheets.

That said, I wrote something that I hope can be useful.
I have made an excel parser that raised events we can listen to. Here I used the events to generate an HtmlFile, but It could be a Markdown one.
Keep your critical mind when reading my code : It's a draft, improvements can be done and I may be wrong in my design :)

And to finish, you can have a look to this class : [ExcelToHtmlConverter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hssf/converter/ExcelToHtmlConverter.html), source code [here](https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/259c9967efb354a0feff2a861ac8bd20582b6562/src/scratchpad/src/org/apache/poi/hssf/converter/ExcelToHtmlConverter.java) : maybe you should start here if it fits your needs, even if the code is not very clean and readable.

```
public ExcelToHtml {
    public File generate(File excelFile, Style style) {
        ExcelToHtmlWriter excelToHtmlWriter = new ExcelToHtmlWriter(style);
        ExcelParser excelParser = new ExcelParser(excelFile, excelToHtmlWriter);
        excelParser.parse();
        return excelToHtmlWriter.generatedFile();
    }
}

public class ExcelParser {

    private final File excelFile;
    private final ExcelFileEventListener listener;

    public ExcelParser(File excelFile, ExcelFileEventListener listener) {
        this.excelFile = excelFile;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void parse() {
        try (InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(excelFile)) {
            parseWorkbook(inp);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("error during parsing", e);
        }
    }

    private void parseWorkbook(InputStream inp) throws IOException {
        listener.start();
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
        int numberOfSheets = wb.getNumberOfSheets();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSheets; i++) {
            parseSheet(wb, i);
        }
        listener.end();
    }

    private void parseSheet(Workbook wb, int i) {
        listener.newSheet();
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(i);
        for (Row row : sheet) {
            parseRow(row);
        }
        listener.endSheet();
    }

    private void parseRow(Row row) {
        listener.newRow();
        for (Cell cell : row) {
            listener.newCell();
            listener.cellContent(cell.toString());
            listener.endCell();
        }
        listener.endRow();
    }
}

public class ExcelToHtmlWriter implements ExcelFileEventListener {

    private static final String LINE_SEPARATOR = System.lineSeparator();
    private final Style style;

    private FileWriter writer;
    private File tmpFile;

    public ExcelToHtmlWriter(Style style) {
        this.style = style;
    }

    @Override
    public void newSheet() {
        write("<table>");
        write(LINE_SEPARATOR);
    }

    @Override
    public void endSheet() {
        write("</table>");
        write(LINE_SEPARATOR);
    }

    @Override
    public void newRow() {
        write("<tr>");
        write(LINE_SEPARATOR);
    }

    @Override
    public void endRow() {
        write(LINE_SEPARATOR + "</tr>" + LINE_SEPARATOR);
    }

    @Override
    public void newCell() {
        write("<td>");
    }

    @Override
    public void endCell() {
        write("</td>");
    }

    @Override
    public void cellContent(String value) {
        write(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        try {
            tmpFile = File.createTempFile("test", ".tmp");
            writer = new FileWriter(tmpFile);
            write("<html>" + LINE_SEPARATOR);
            write("<head>" + LINE_SEPARATOR);
            write("<style>" + LINE_SEPARATOR);
            write(style.content());
            write("</style>" + LINE_SEPARATOR);
            write("</head>" + LINE_SEPARATOR);
            write("<body>" + LINE_SEPARATOR);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("unable to initialize file", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void end() {
        try {
            write("</body>" + LINE_SEPARATOR);
            write("</html>" + LINE_SEPARATOR);
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("unbale to close writer", e);
        }
    }

    public File generatedFile() {
        return tmpFile;
    }

    private void write(String toWrite) {
        try {
            writer.write(toWrite);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException ioException) {
            } finally {
                throw new RuntimeException("unable to write to file", e);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Style {
    private final boolean cellBorders;

    public Style(boolean cellBorders) {
        this.cellBorders = cellBorders;
    }

    public String content() {
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder("td {");
        content.append(System.lineSeparator());
        content.append("padding: 9px;");
        if (cellBorders) {
            content.append(System.lineSeparator());
            content.append("border: 1px solid black;");
            content.append(System.lineSeparator());
            content.append("border-collapse: collapse;");
        }
        content.append(System.lineSeparator());
        content.append("}");
        content.append(System.lineSeparator());
        return content.toString();
    }
}

interface ExcelFileEventListener {
    void newSheet();
    void start();
    void end();
    void endSheet();
    void newRow();
    void endRow();
    void newCell();
    void endCell();
    void cellContent(String value);
}
```